# Throughput bottleneck in browser websockets

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, websocket, autobahn

I'm trying to use websockets to stream data from an autobahn/twisted server to a javascript client in a browser. The connection.onmessage handler seems to have some sort of throughput restriction to about 3mps, this seems to be enforced regardless of the message transmission characteristics. The server does this:

```
import time
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import *
from twisted.web.resource import *
from twisted.web.static import Data
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import *
from autobahn.twisted.resource import *

pageHtml = '''<html><head><script>
function wsReceive(e) {
  received += e.data.byteLength;
  duration = Date.now() - startTime;
  console.log("Rx "+received+" bytes in "+duration+"ms: "+received/(duration*1000.0));
}
function init() {
  startTime = Date.now();
  received = 0;
  connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/speedtest');
  connection.onmessage = wsReceive;
  connection.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
}
</script></head>
<body onload="javascript:init()"></body></html>'''
dataSize = 1 * 2 ** 20
msgSize  = 10 * 2 ** 10

class SpeedTest(WebSocketServerProtocol):
  def onOpen(self):
    start = time.clock()
    for i in range(dataSize/msgSize):
      payload = bytearray(msgSize)
      self.sendMessage(bytes(payload), True)
    print "Transmit to autobahn queue: %.1fms" % ((time.clock()-start)*1000.0)

factory = WebSocketServerFactory()
factory.protocol = SpeedTest

tree = Resource()
frontPage = Data(pageHtml,"text/html")
tree.putChild('',           frontPage)
tree.putChild('index.html', frontPage)
tree.putChild('speedtest',  WebSocketResource(factory))
reactor.listenTCP(8080,     Site(tree))
reactor.run()
```

Nothing complicated - just blasts a series of messages at any client that connects. I'm testing it against the javascript running in Safari and Chrome (OSX 10.11, pypy-4.0.1). To find the maximum performance (everything is running on an internal loopback connection) I connect to it with this:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor

from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, \
    WebSocketClientProtocol, \
    connectWS


import time

class SpeedTest(WebSocketClientProtocol):
  def onOpen(self):
    self.startTime = time.clock()
    self.received = 0
    print "Connected"
    self.sendMessage("Hello")

  def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
    duration = time.clock() - self.startTime
    self.received += len(payload)
    print "Rx %d bytes in %.1fms: %.1fmps" % (self.received, duration*1000.0, (self.received / duration) // 1000000.0)


factory = WebSocketClientFactory(u"ws://127.0.0.1:8080/speedtest")
factory.protocol = SpeedTest
connectWS(factory)
reactor.run()
```

Regardless of how I set dataSize and msgSize I see about 240mps. When I connect with either Safari or Chrome it maxs out at 3mps. For example this shows 10MB of data in 1MB messages.
[image: 1024K messages, 10MB total]

This shows the same 10MB split into 64K messages, the throughput is basically identical. The time between the calls to onmessages simply spread out more to preserve the rate.
[image]

I see the same in Chrome: the timeline in chrome shows that the browser is about 95% idle - all of the wait time is occurring outside of javascript, before the data is handed over to the onmessage event handler. So basically my question is two parts:

1. Why does this happen, as in where is the bottleneck (and does it
   occur on other platforms)?
2. Can I fix it to improve the throughput to the javascript client?

Edit: Realised that I didn't test this on firefox. It peaks at 85mbps, but also seems to throttle the connection to 30mbps under some conditions (more, smaller messages). A partial answer to part 1 is then: use firefox.

Comment: The fact that different browsers show different limits suggests that this is a browser-side limitation. If that is the case then it's unlikely there is anything that can be done on the part of the library, as very little of the browser innards are exposed to JS.

Comment: That makes sense, with any luck somebody with experience of the firefox code could comment on where / how the throttle is implemented...